# fstab creates directory without execute permissions

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab

Is it possible that a directory is created only with read permission by a kernel module ( don't know which one is responsible for fstab ) ? Like r--r--r-- ?

I have an entry in fstab

```
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom auto noauto,user,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

and it leads to a creation of a directory called /media/cdrom with read permissions ( without write and execute ), as soon as I mount the CD using the Filemanager ( by clicking on the cdrom icon ).

The problem is that I am unable to enter the directory.

Comment: What filesystem do you have on the CD? Plain iso9660 or something that supports Unix-style permissions? Also, what OS/Linux distro is this? (I don't know if it matters)

Comment: Try creating `/media/cdrom` manually.

Comment: It's possible, but it shouldn't happen. What file manager are you using? On what distribution? Does it make a difference if you run `mount /media/cdrom` on the command line (while the drive is not mounted)?

Comment: @Gilles: It does make a difference if I run it manually -t is9660 and mounted at /media/cdrom. There is no problem then. But I fail to understand why would a file manager ( in this case it is thunar / xubuntu ) create a file directory with such strange permissions. A non superuser would have to bypass the terminal commands by clicking on the CDROM icon which appears as soon as the kernel detects a CD in the CD tray.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information, and the version of Ubuntu. I don't think Thunar uses `fstab`, but I'm not sure. Have you checked for reported bugs?